# Custom user login page by creating a plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, users, user-registration

I am creating a custom user interface (separate from the WordPress user system) that relies heavy on values from a mysql database. I have figured out how to access these values, and with PHP files made a custom login page, but I don't know how to integrate these php files into my WordPress site. I was thinking of using a custom made plugin, but only really know how to use shortcodes. The login system is based off of this: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php. The problem is that it requires directing to separate PHP files and getting values saved through sessions. Does anyone how I could implement this? Should I instead being creating a custom theme, with separate templates for each page? Would that work?

Comment: Why are you using WordPress if you want to replace the backend and login with your own?

Comment: I want to keep the backend, sorry I phrased that wrong. I want a custom user interface, that gets its information from a mysql database. I was hired to implement this into the wordpress site

Comment: Did you read over all the documentation provided by WordPress about theme and plugin development ? It will really help to have some basics concepts clear, in order to describe and then achieve what you want to do.

Comment: I can actually help you with this... What you want to do is create a 'template' in your plugin that will replace the default WP login, then link your custom PHP that pulls data from the other MySQL DB into it to your custom login form.  Then all you're doing is redirecting the wp-login.php url to your custom page.

Comment: Thank you both. In creating a template in the plug in, will I be able to 'redirect' to other php files. currently there is a login php file that redirects to a user menu, and then the specific user information...